# How to get a (high quality) FLV version of your youtube video?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flv, videotexture

I need to get a link of a FLV verion of a youtube video so I can play it in mobile, using Adobe Air (VideoTexture).

I'm currently using this library: https://github.com/myflashlab/AS3-youtube-parser-video-link

Which works, the only problem is that the only FLV version of the video I get has a 426x240 resolution, which is not acceptable. MP4 does have a 720p version but it's not displaying on iOS.

If anyone knows how to ask for/obtain the correct link to a FLV youtube video, would be great.

Comment: The line that select the quality of the video (in the example) is : `if (currVideoData.type == VideoType.VIDEO_MP4 && currVideoData.quality == VideoQuality.MEDIUM){ /* .. */ }`, you have just to change it to the desired quality when it's available of course ...

Comment: Yeah, the thing is that I actually have only one option for FLV videos, 240p. Also I tried an MP4 video directly from my device and it runs OK on iOS, that makes me wonder if the problem is the codec YT videos are using.